# Remove +0000 From Date Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a Issue i am using this code in 'View did Load' and DateText is the UIOutlet of Text Field

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
[self.DateText setInputView:datePicker];

[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.DateText.inputView;
self.DateText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
```

and the Ouptut i am getting in the TextField(DepartureDateText) is

2013-06-13 07:38:22 +0000

Can anyone Suggest me how can i get rid of +0000 and also what Does +0000 indicate.

Comment: `+0000` specifies timezone.

Comment: read `NSDateFormatter`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: it it the actual timezone, and you are able to format the date in any format, using the `NSDateFormatter` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to change the [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate) to the local date time representation:

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.DateText.inputView;
    self.DateText.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:picker.date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];;
}
```

I highly recommend using [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the `NSDateFormatterStyle` to represent your dates. This will format the date the way the user wants it.

Answer (score -1):

By using dateFormatter you can do anything with your date;

```
    NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    myDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss";

    NSString *todayString = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate: datePicker.date];
```

Comment: Where is monthFormatter is myDateFormatter